# Full file path in status bar

Tags: statusline, plugin-lightline

I'm a Vim user and I'm not a Vim developer. I collect some useful vim plugins in `~/.vim/`and add some usable Vim commands in my `~/.vimrc`. Now it seems like IDE as this pic.

I would like to add a full file path in the status bar but couldn't find in which place I can do it.

I know some short key like <kbd>Ctrl-g</kbd>.

How can I do that?

[image]

Comment: Are you using a plugin to manage your status line (e.g. [vim-airline](https://github.com/vim-airline/vim-airline) or [powerline](https://github.com/powerline/powerline))?

Comment: I don't know. I run `find .vim/ -name '*air*'` , only ale_linter return.

Comment: Could you tell us what is the result of `:set statusline?`.

Comment: thanks.`statusline=%{lightline#link()}%#LightlineLeft_inactive_0#%( %t %)%#LightlineLeft_inactive_0_1# %#LightlineMiddle_inactive#%=%#LightlineRight_inactive_1_2# %#LightlineRight_inactive_1#%( %3p%% %)%#LightlineRight_inactive_0_1# %#LightlineRight_inactive_0#%( %3l:%
-2c %)`

Comment: Thanks :-) It seems that you are using the [lightline](https://github.com/itchyny/lightline.vim) plugin to control your status line.

Comment: you are right,I found it `.vim_runtime/sources_non_forked/lightline.vim/autoload/lightline.vim`

Comment: shall I add somethings to it?

Comment: I can't understand, why someone gave minus reputation?and why not explain his/her considration for that?

Comment: I am not the down-voter, but I _suspect_ that the downvote is for the following reason: your question does not provide enough information to get a good answer. It took some time in the comment to find out that you are using the lightline plugin, so answers customizing the statusline need to target that. You can [edit] to include this information, which probably should have been there to begin with. More generally, it's a good idea to include as much relevant information as possible up front.

Comment: thanks for your response, but I did know it, @VivianDeSmedt help me to find it.as I told I'm not vim developer, just vim user

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To show the full path in the status line using [lightline](https://github.com/itchyny/lightline.vim) you can add the following line in your `.vimrc` file:

```
if !exists('g:lightline')
  let g:lightline = {}
endif
if !exists('g:lightline.component')
  let g:lightline.component = {}
endif
let g:lightline.component.filename='%F'
```

[image]

Comment: it changes the status line totally and changes the colorSchema, also it would disappear after `:w`. I would like to add a new column after the existing columns. in the above pic after the file name.

Comment: If you don't include the propose changes what is the result of `:echo g:lightline`. I suspect you already have some lightline configuration that need to be merged.

Comment: I only vim fan, I don't know about vim sysntax and ...

Comment: the result of your edition is like the previous result. disappear after `:w`, change color and change it totally/

Comment: I suspect some interaction with other plugins. I would be you I suppose I would try to reproduce the problem with a minimum Vim configuration to understand what part of the configuration lead to the effect described.

Comment: You could also verify that you have a recent version of lightline. Can you tell us what is the version of Vim you are using `:version`?

Comment: `VIM - Vi IMproved 8.1 (2018 May 18, compiled Jan 11 2023 23:54:11)`. I added many plugins.

Comment: thats worked. it needs to close vim and reopen.thanks to you.

Comment: You are welcome! Thanks for the feedback :-)